# REST API with web application(JSP,Servlets)

Tags: jsp, rest, servlets, jersey, url-pattern

I have one normal servlet and one jersey specific REST related servlet i.e.ServletContainer configured in web.xml. 
Case 1 -
Url pattern for normal servlet is "/login"
Url pattern for other REST servlet is "/*"
In this case all request will got REST servlet. Request for login also goes to tht Servlet only.
Case 2 - 
If Url pattern for REST servlet changed to "/rest/* " (which root path of my test resource class)
And Url pattern for normal servlet as it was "/login"
Only normal request for /login works, but any REST requests doesn't work.

Can anyone help me in this??

Comment: what application server are you using? what is its configuration (especially deploy contexts). Please elaborate: which paths are set in web.xml files, and which ones via annotation.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess given what you've told us (**I'm assuming you're running two different webapps**):

### Set contexts in your tomcat configuration server.xml

```
<Context path="" docBase="/yourworkspace/project-webapp/docs/" ... />
<Context path="/rest" docBase="/yourworkspace/project-rest/docs/" ... />
```

### Application Mapping

In rest-web.xml (your jersey web application)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>project-rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In jsp-web.xml (your jsp web application)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>project-webapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### In your Jersey application, your URL mapping should start on `/`

Example:

```
@Path("/car")
@Named("carResource")
public interface CarResource {

  @GET
  @Path("{carId}")
  @Consumes("text/plain")
  @Produces("application/xml")
  Car getCar(@PathParam("carId") Long carId);
```

should handle `GET http://domain.org/rest/car/42` requests.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve ? In case 2 try to change it to this /rest/*.

Comment: I just want to call rest api when am using rest uri created.

Comment: N i want to call normal servlet when am using url as /login.

Comment: if you specifie the url pattern like this: /rest/* and and have a class wich is annoted by this: @Path( "/test" ) then the following call: http:// {host}:{port}/{appName}/rest/test should invoke the service.

Comment: Thanks a lot man................!!!!! It worked....!! This small example cleared the confusion...!! :-)